# Зачем передавать в функцию структуру, если можно передать указатель на нее?

Tags: c++, указатели

Читаю книгу по С++ (до этого изучал Си), главу про ссылки. Часто приходится видеть код, где в функции передаются целые структуры (и/или возвращаются функцией), хотя, имхо, лучше было бы передовать указатель на структуру. Подскажите, какие выйгрышы дают каждый из вариантов.

PS сам я очень редко создаю структуры в регистре, обычно использую для этого указатели и динамическое выделение памяти (особенно когда дело касается списков и деревьев) и поэтому никогда и не пытался передавать структуры в функции целиком. А доступ к членам всегда осуществлял с помощью ->, а не операции точки.

Comment: Ну, например, если вы хотите менять структуру по ходу дела, но не сам оригинал. Или возвращать одновременно несколько значений, объединенных в структуру...

Comment: Если я все правильно понял (то о чем вы говорите), то это делается и с помощью указателей тоже.

Comment: *"Часто приходится видеть код, где в функции передаются целые структуры (и/или возвращаются функцией)"* тогда при чем тут ссылки? Вообще было бы хороши привести пример такого кода, а то есть ощущение что вы путаете передачу по ссылке / перемещение / отложенную инициализацию.

Comment: Блин, теперь не могу удалить вопрос. Черт!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем передовать в функцию структуру, если можно передать указатель на нее?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786411/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5)

Comment: Скорее всего  вы видите код, где вам *кажется*, что передаются структуры (по значению). На самом деле там происходит передача *по ссылке*. Выяснить это можно лишь посмотрев на описание вызываемой функции. (Следствие -- в практическом программировании ссылки это зло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что желательно знать и использовать все механизмы языка, а не только те, в которых вы уверены на данный момент.

Передача сущностей в функцию по указателям является наименее оправданным действием, так как содержит риск передачи невалидного указателя, проверка которого никак не гарантируется языком.

Для передачи чего-то, что должно изменяться внутри функции, предпочтительнее использовать ссылки, нежели указатели. (Ссылку в никуда получить сложнее, чем указатель в никуда).

Для того, чтобы передать копию экземпляра структуры, достаточно просто ее передать целиком и пользоваться таки точкой.

Answer (score 0):

Передача по ссылке позволяет обеспечить перегрузку операторов и при этом избежать копирования тяжелых структур. Если вы переключаетесь с сей на плюсы, то можете рассматривать ссылки как альтернативу указателям. Их поведение с точки зрения управлением памятью совпадает. Например, не стоит возвращать ссылку/указатель на локальный объект функции, так как он будет уничтожен при выходе из функции.

Чтобы ответить более предметно имеет смысл добавить в вопрос вызвавший сомнения код.

Comment: ...но есть особый случай с возвратом константной ссылки, про который тоже надо помнить!

http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/01/const.html

Comment: @gdb там нет возврата ссылки. Там обыкновенное привязывание временного объекта к ссылке. И ссылка эта не обязана быть lvalue-ссылкой на константу. Она может быть rvalue-ссылкой.

Comment: @gbg, возвращать любую (включая константную) ссылку можно только на постоянный объект, на временный нельзя.

Comment: @Croessmah я в данном случае отвечаю на фразу автора о том, что "Их _[ссылок]_ поведение с точки зрения управлением памятью совпадает" - нет, не полностью, есть особый случай с возвратом константной ссылки.

Comment: @gbg а как Вы возьмете адрес у временного объекта, возвращаемого из функции? Это если проводить проекцию примера на указатель.