# Зачем передовать в функцию структуру, если можно передать указатель на нее?

Tags: c++, указатели

Уже задавал похожий вопрос, но меня не правильно поняли, привожу код ниже:
Зачем делать так:

```
struct st fun (struct st);
```

Если можно сделать так:

```
struct st *fun (struct *st);
```

, что, имхо, эффективнее.

Comment: Когда структура используется как аргумент функции, передается вся структура с помощью стандартной передачи по значению. Это означает, что любые изменения, внесенные в содержимое структуры внутри функции, не повлияют на структуру, используемую в качестве аргумента. Могу предположить, что два эти способа имеют место быть, и используются в разных случаях.

Comment: Первый вариант может понадобиться, если нужны копии структур, второй вариант в С++ вообще использовать не стоит, так как сырые указатели не есть хорошо.

Comment: Вам в том вопросе предложили привести пример функции о которой идет речь, что бы можно было сказать зачем именно в этой ситуации сделано так. Подразумевалось, что примером должна быть функция целиком, со всем телом, а не только заголовок

Comment: Ну я именно на это вам и отвечал в комментарии...

Comment: ну и если структура маленькая, то её копирование вполне может быть эффективнее, чем постоянные косвенные обращения через указатель. Кроме того, указатели и при возврате и при приеме придется проверить на nullptr. Также стоит учесть RVO/NRVO/copy elision оптимизации, которые исключат копирование возвращаемого значения. Также с копиями удобнее работать, например, при многопоточном исполнении, не боясь повредить данные другого потока, не говоря уже о синхронизации.

Comment: @Mike меня не волнует само тело функции, мне интересно почему делают "вот так, а не так". Могу лишь сказать, если вы не поняли, что делают ф-ции: он идентичны, заисключением того, что в первом случае принимаются сами структуры, а во втором указатели на них.

Comment: Они ничуть не идентичны! Ведь что в теле - вы не знаете.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так делают, потому что внутри тела функции (которое вас не интересует) нужно что бы параметры были именно такими, а не ссылками. И без рассмотрения тела функции невозможно сказать зачем так делают. Можно найти массу причин делать именно так, так же как и массу причин делать по другому, но все решается в теле. Вы спрашиваете почему в машину заливают бензин, но при этом ничего не хотите знать о том, что у нее под капотом

Comment: @Mike ну вот я не понимаю: что не понятного? Что непонятного в словах: идентичные действия? Вот что в этих словах не понятного? Мне единственное, что интересно: зачем может понадобится передовать целую структуру, хотя те же действия можно сделать через указатель?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Покажите мне эти идентичные функции, одна из которых берет указатель, а другая копию. Вероятно они делают разные действия, поэтому и принимают разные аргументы, которые более удобны им. Функция берущая указатель может менять переданный параметр, а берущая саму структуру - не может. Если вызывающая функция должна быть уверена, что ее данные не изменят, она передаст копию (либо сделав ее самостоятельно, либо передав по значению, что бы компилятор сам это сделал).

Comment: @Mike вы понимаете разницу между "идентичными действиями" и "идентичными функциями"?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Нет, по моему идентичные функции совершают идентичные действия

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch отвечая на ваш коммент под ответом: если вы хотите знать, почему так делают, когда это не оправдано с точки зрения эффективности (передача копии, что бы в ней выполнили инкремент и ее вернули), то либо передаваемая структура очень мала и ее эффективнее передать через стек, либо это писал кто то из 95% программистов, которые об эффективности вообще не думают и ему просто так было удобнее и возможно красивее выглядит

Answer (score 2):

Давайте взглянем иначе.

```
struct st * func();
```

Расскажите, указатель на что следует возвращать?

Или если есть функция `g(struct st *)`, которая *изменяет* переданную ей структуру, но вам - в вашей функции `f` - ее менять не нужно? Что вы будете делать?

```
f(struct st * s) {
    struct st m;
    memcpy(&m,s,sizeof(m));
    g(&m);
```

или просто

```
f(struct st s) {
    g(&s);
```

(и это я еще не рассматривал случай сложного копирования :))

Придумывать еще примеры или хватит? :)

Comment: Ладно, спрошу более развернуто (хотя мне в комментах уже ответили на мой вопрос): нужна функция, которая, к примеру, увеличивает член структуры на 1, или изменяет все члены структуры - не важно. Затем, уже в main, новое значение выводится на экран (используя возвращаемое значение функции). Меня интересует: в каких случаях и почему целесообразнее использовать передачу самой структуры, а не указателя на нее?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch если вы менчете структуру то выбора нету, или указатель или ссылка...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, так как вам немного сложно , я решил исправить свой ответ в вашем прошлом вопросе. Взгляните там.  Или сами пишите простые структуры и проверьте их в функции с указателем  и   значением.  Берите в конце концов разные коды и в функциях измените аргумент  не ссыльку на указатель

Comment: @Harry, я ометил ваш ответ, но у меня вопрос к вам. в теле функции   struct st m;  или просто обьявить  st m; ?

Comment: А это зависит от языка :) В C++ и `st m` хватит, в C надо `struct` явно писать. Потому в С и распространены всякие объявления типа - `typedef struct _st { ... } st;` - чтоб `struct` не таскать за собой...

Answer (score 1):

```
class T {... T(const T& ); ...};
```

почему в конструктор коопирования не передается указатель?.. Не думаю, что вы сами не сможете ответить...